# React HOC: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) guide to try and write a React Higher Order Component.

I am trying to have a reusable window component that will act as a container for other components, providing style and behaviour.

I am testing it with a Player component that for now just returns a ReactPlayer component from the npm package react-player

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


function Window(WrappedComponent){
    return class extends Component{
        render(){
            return (
                <div className="window">
                    <WrappedComponent/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Window();
```

This is the code for the player component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import Window from './Window.js'

class Player extends Component {
    render () {
        return <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKKvG0_KdM' playing />
    }
}

const PlayerWindow = Window(Player);

export default PlayerWindow;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `export default Window();` to `export default Window;`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets from `export default Window();`
Alternatively, when calling the function you could write

```
> export const Window = function Window(WrappedComponent){
>     return class extends Component{
>         render(){
>             return (
>                 <div className="window">
>                     <WrappedComponent/>
>                  </div>
>             );
>         }
>     } 
> }
```